# Match Individual Words In String In VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Excel 2013 here - and am attempting to match the value in cell D to the value in cell C.  The part that is leaving me pulling my hair out, is the fact that if a single word exists in column C it should be removed from column D.

For example

```
Column C          Column D
Red Hairy Hats    Hairy Cowpies
```

Since both fields contain the word `Hairy` it should be updated to read like so

```
Column C          Column D
Red Hairy Hats    Cowpies
```

I can not uncover how to do a wildcard match on string comparison in Excel VBA.  I have this syntax which does an **Exact** match, but how could I do single words from the string like in my example above?

```
Dim i As Long
Dim resArry
dataArry = Cells(1).CurrentRegion
ReDim resArry(UBound(dataArry, 1) - 1, 1)
For i = 2 To UBound(dataArry, 1)
    If InStr(1, dataArry(i, 3), dataArry(i, 4), vbBinaryCompare) Then
        resArry(i - 2, 0) = ""
    Else
        resArry(i - 2, 0) = dataArry(i, 4)
    End If
Next

Range("D2").Resize(UBound(resArry, 1)) = resArry
```

Comment: You can use Split(v, " ") on a single cell value to get an array of words from each of the two cells you want to compare.  Loop over the words in the ColD array and see if they exist in the ColC array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RegExp option with variant arrays.

Create a pattern for each C string against each D string for a whole word only replacement

> \b(Red|Hairy|Hats)\b

etc

```
Sub Interesting()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim X, Y
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim ObjRegex As Object

Set rng1 = Range([c1], Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp))
X = rng1.Value2
Y = rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value2
Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With ObjRegex
.Global = True
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    .Pattern = "\b(" & Join(Split(X(lngCnt, 1), Chr(32)), "|") & ")\b"
    Y(lngCnt, 1) = .Replace(Y(lngCnt, 1), vbNullString)
    Next
End With

rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Y

End Sub
```

Comment: I like the use of RegExp! However, it is not removing values?

Comment: I am eager to make it work. Seems like when `C = xxx yyy` and `D = yyy zzz ttt` it doesn't remove the "yyy"?

Comment: it seems to work like a charm without those `\b`. Nice idea but needs some finalization :)

Comment: There's a typo in the Regex.  Should be `.Pattern = "\b(" & Join(Split(X(lngCnt, 1), Chr(32)), "|") & ")\b"`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yep, that seems to fix it in my tests.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - yes making that small update works perfect for me.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @brettdj Glad to help. I suggest you also remove the square brackets in line 3 of your response.

Comment: @IcyPopTarts you might also need `WorksheetFunction.Trim` instead of `VBA.Trim` on the result. In Google Sheets it is `=Trim(RegExReplace(D1,"\b(" & Substitute(C1," ","|") & ")\b",""))`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - wow, a sloppy morning. At least I tested before posting. But small mercy!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, since I’m a bit rusty with VBA, but rather than use `instr` to look for matches, you might have more success splitting both strings into arrays.

The process would be something like this:

- split both strings using space
- for each element in the second array

  - test whether it’s in the first array
  - if it is, remove the element
- Join the second array back into a string using spaces
- Repeat and rinse

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim C As String, D As String
    C = "Red Hairy Hats"
    D = "hairy cowpies"
    Debug.Print RemoveMatches(C, D)
End Sub

Private Function RemoveMatches(C As String, D As String) As String
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Sp = Split(C)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
        If InStr(1, D, Sp(i), vbTextCompare) Then
            D = Trim(Replace(D, Sp(i), "", Compare:=vbTextCompare))
        End If
    Next i
    RemoveMatches = D
End Function
```

Comment: That works, but I am needing to read in cell values, not hardcode values...How could I read in the cell values for each cell in C and each cell in D to an array and compare using your function?

Comment: In the code represented in my example as Sub Test() you should have code like C = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 3).Value where 10 is the row and 3 the column ("C"). Since you probably loop through your sheet, you would need to replace the hard value, at least for the row, with a variable used in a For ... Next loop.